# What is the terminology for the page to which the user is redirected to, after successful login?

Tags: web-app, terminology, homepage, authentication, landing-page

I did quite a search for this both online and offline, but couldn't find a satisfiable answer. Some of my colleagues suggested terminologies like Dashboard, Home page, Welcome page, landing page, etc. It's true that a great deal of web apps redirect users to a dashboard page after login but the page is called dashboard, not because of this but because it has stuff like app status or profile status. Also a home page is the usual term for the first page in an application which can be available even when not authenticated. Welcome page is also a term usually used for an entry point page just like home page. And from numerous searches regarding Landing page, I guess it's a term coined by marketers and advertisers synonymous to lead capture page.

> A landing page, sometimes known as a "lead capture page" or a "lander", or a "destination page", is a single web page that appears in response to clicking on a search engine optimized search result or an online advertisement. - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landing_page

So, for the above reasons, i don't think any of the above terms are good enough for the description "The page to which the user is redirected to, after successful login".

I expect my fellow stack exchangers will find an answer for this or share their views regarding this question. 
Thanks  in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

As you said, dashboard is the wrong term if the page the user gets redirected to is not offering dashboard-like data.

I would call this page the **front page**, home page is not wrong either but its kind a misleading since under "home page" everyone just understands the general website.

I don't think there is a 100% definition since its depending on the informations the user gets shown on this page.

Answer (score 2):

The page should be described by what it does, not by consensus.

Therefore, if the page that users are taken to, after a successful log-in is a dashboard, call it a dashboard.

Trying to bless it with an unfamiliar fancy term will only serve to confuse users, and that's what we try to avoid here.

Comment: I agree and I think that a dashboard still has to be called a dashboard whether it is used as the first page after login or not. Imagine we're two UX engineers discussing about the login requirements of a web app. And one of us say, "Okay, let's keep the dashboard page as X", here X being the terminology for the page to redirect to after a successful login. My question is, what do we say in place of X ?

Answer (score 0):

In my company, the site **without logging in**, is a big multi-page retail environment the user can use to find all kind of information about the services the compan offers. We call that the retail space or **retail environment**.

The environment **after login**, is seen by the client as 'My Environment' (so *their environment* technically). It's where the client use our services and manage their account and such. We call it the client space or **client environment**.

The first page the client sees after logging in, we call that the **client home page**.

Answer (score 0):

I think "landing page" is the right page, that is if you redirect people that specifically logged in by going to the login page to this page, i.e (it's the default page for people who didn't get to your website by clicking a direct link to a secured page). NB: People that got on the login page by trying to access a secure page should be redirected to the page they were trying to access after successful login, not the "landing page".